# Send twilio whatsapp message from Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twilio

I am trying to send a WhatsApp message using twilio's HTTP endpoint but it is failing with error

> {"code": 21602, "message": "Message body is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21602", "status": 400}

I did not purposefully add `'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as the URLFetchApp [adds the same automatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).

```js
function sampletTextMessage(){
  var ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var ACCOUNT_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    'headers' : {
      "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + ACCOUNT_TOKEN),
    },
    'payload' :{
      'body' : 'Your Twilio code is 1238432',
      'to' : 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXX3',
      'from': 'whatsapp:+1XXXXXXXXX6',
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  var url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + ACCOUNT_SID + "/Messages.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your case is wrong, capitalize To, From, and Body.

Reference:
[How to Send SMS from a Google Spreadsheet](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html)

```
  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "YOURTWILIONUMBER"
  };
```